# how to validate date in textfield java to enter in ms access

Tags: java, netbeans

i want my code to validate date according to format , day month aslo it shoud not exceed day month value...and even if i enter in any format **mm/dd/yyyy** or **mm/dd/yyyy** or **yyyy/mm/dd** it should validate all because ms access support all format.

and how to udate it also for that my code is:

```
        Connection connection;
    String text = txtUpdate.getText();
    int Update = Integer.parseInt(text);
    String Name = txtName.getText();
    String Email = txtEmail.getText();
    String Mobile = txtMobile.getText();
    String Address = txtAddress.getText();
    String Dob = txtDob.getText();

            if (check_Name() && check_Email() && check_Mobile() && check_Address() && check_Dob()) {
        try {
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:NewPData");
            String query = "update Table1 set Name='" + Name + "' , Email='" + Email + "' , Mobile=" + Mobile + ", Address= '" + Address + "', DOB=" +Dob + ", where ID=" + Update;
            PreparedStatement ps_Statement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            ps_Statement.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(panelID, "Record Updated Successfully");
            connection.close();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DO THIS

```
public java.sql.Date checkdate(String Dob)
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
    try {
       java.util.Date yourDate = sdf.parse( Dob );
       java.sql.Date yoursqlDate= new java.sql.Date(yourDate.getTime());
       return yoursqlDate;
    } catch ( Exception ex ) {
       // Your Catch Block
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: grtt @Bhavik its solved but `java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in UPDATE statement.` in query plz ans

Comment: @spb111 : DOB requires '' ( single inverted commas) too. you dont have single inverted commas. however since you are using PreparedStatement why don't you use different set() to avoid syntax errors. http://www.roseindia.net/jdbc/prepared-statement-example.shtml will help you notice the use of ?'s

Answer (score 1):

Use `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` class to parse the string (text) as per specified date format.

Answer (score 0):

As for my previous answer, you should use SimpleDateFormat to parse the String to Date.

EDIT:

`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");`

```
try {
   yourDate = sdf.parse( Dob );
} catch ( Exception ex ) {
   // Your Catch Block
}</code>
```

You may use MMM if your month input happens to be in word. i.e 12-Nov-2012 etc.

EDIT:

To insert the value prior to this format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", add this code under your parse.

`Dob = sdf.format(yourDate);`

```
String query = "update Table1 set Name='" + Name + "' , Email='" + Email + "' , Mobile=" + Mobile + ", Address= '" + Address + "', DOB='" +Dob + "' where ID=" + Update;
```

Date requires single quotation marks. Plus, eliminate the comma after DOB ='" + Dob + "'

Comment: i have tried it gives   java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "22/12/1991"

Comment: If ever your code throw an exception, please post the line number where the error takes part.

Comment: By any chance, can you post your code together with the parse.

Comment: i tried this code after ur suggestion                            `Date yourDate = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyy");
        try {
            yourDate = (Date) sdf.parse(Dob);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }`                                                        error at the place of pare method

Comment: Oh, what was the input? You can't actually parse different format.

Comment: i pass this input 22/12/1991

Comment: I'm very sorry, please use dd/MM/yy instead.

Comment: You may use MMM if your month input would be in word. e.g 12-Nov-2012 etc.

Comment: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date

Comment: yesterdays also i was very close to solution but got this only exception

Comment: So problem regarding the parse has been eliminated. Now it's the sql... Let's see...

Comment: 'SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");' date format should always be like this

Comment: I'm sorry, if I misunderstood your question. Do you mean that you want to insert the date in yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format? Well, if yes, you should also adjust your date inputs

Comment: hmm right mechael anyways i am very close to solution just getting syntax error in update statement ...you have helped me a lot thnx michael :)

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please try the revision. :) You are always welcome

Comment: i am using                                            ' java.sql.Date yoursqlDate=null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        try {
             java.util.Date yourDate = sdf.parse( Dob );
             yoursqlDate= new java.sql.Date(yourDate.getTime());
             
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }'                                                       this code now and problem now is only in query statement whether to add single quotes or ## both doesn't  work

Comment: Have you tried to add this code below your parse?Dob = sdf.format(yourDate); then your query should be DOB = '" + Dob + "'

Comment: yes bro but its always gives 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date' So the code i have just  written is the solution to this problem now i need exact query to update date

Comment: long longDate = yourDate.getTime();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(longDate); DOB = '" + sqlDate + "' this should work